# How to return values from mapply with factors function arguments and output

Tags: r, mapply

I am having trouble getting values instead of factors from the output of an mapply function.  The code below tries to find the temperature at a particular location and time.

```
now <- Sys.time()

datetime<-as.POSIXct(seq(now, length.out = 5, by = "hours"), tz = "GMT")
location<-c("Chicago","Detroit","New York","Cleveland","Atlanta")
temperature<-c(2,9,4,8,59)

df1 <- data.frame(datetime, location, temperature)

# add 3 hours to System time
now <- Sys.time() + 3*60*60

datetime<-as.POSIXct(seq(now, length.out = 5, by = "hours"), tz = "GMT")
location<-c("Chicago","Cleveland","Chicago","Detroit","Atlanta")
temperature<-c(6,8,3,12,69)

df2 <- data.frame(datetime, location, temperature)

# Data Frame with Location and Time and Temperature data
loc_temp_df <- rbind(df1,df2)

# Add 2 hours to system time
now <- Sys.time() + 2*60*60

datetime<-as.POSIXct(seq(now, length.out = 7, by = "hours"), tz = "GMT")
location<-c("Chicago","Chicago","New York","Atlanta","New York", "Detroit", "Cleveland")

df <- data.frame(datetime, location)

# Function to find temperature at specific location closest to specific time
myfunction <- function(x,y) {
  same_location <- loc_temp_df[which(loc_temp_df$location == y),]
  time_at_location <- as.POSIXct(same_location$datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = "GMT")
  index <- which.min(abs(difftime(x, time_at_location, "mins")))
  same_location[index,]
}

mapply(myfunction, df$datetime, df$location)
```

When i run the code i get factors returned instead of values.  Any idea how i can return values instead of factors?

```
  [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      
datetime    1436564283 1436564283 1436560683 1436567883 1436560683 1436575083 1436567883
location    factor,1   factor,1   factor,1   factor,1   factor,1   factor,1   factor,1  
temperature 6          6          4          59         4          12         8
```

I tried using lapply but could not get it to work in the same way.

Comment: I get error by running this code. `mapply(myfunction, df$datetime, df$location)#
Error in (function (x, y)  : object 'loc_temp_df' not found`

Comment: Sorry, it should be fixed now.

Comment: You can use `Map` i.e. `do.call(rbind,Map(myfunction, df$datetime, df$location))` or `do.call(rbind, mapply(myfunction, df$datetime, df$location, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))`

Comment: That works great akrun.  Thanks.  If you post that as a reply i can give you credit for the right answer.

Comment: Posted that as a solution.  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `Map` or `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` in `mapply` to keep it as `list` and then `rbind`.

```
 do.call(rbind,Map(myfunction, df$datetime, df$location))
```

Or

```
 do.call(rbind, mapply(myfunction, df$datetime, df$location, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```